# Object Oriented Ascii dungeon game

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

I have solved an assignment (Exercise 33) from the [MOOC Object-Oriented programming with Java, part II](https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part2/week-10/), but I'm not enrolled in said course.

> **Assignment Summary**
>
> In this exercise, you implement a dungeon game. In the game, the
>   player is in a dungeon full of vampires. The player has to destroy the
>   vampires before his lamp runs out of battery and the vampires can suck
>   his blood in the darkness. The player can see the vampires with a
>   blinking of their lamp, after which they have to move blind before the
>   following blinking. With one move, the player can walk as many steps
>   as they want.   The game situation, i.e. the dungeon, the player and
>   the vampires are shown in text form. The first line in the print
>   output tells how many moves the player has left (that is to say, how
>   much battery the lamp has). After that, the print output shows player
>   and vampire positions, which in turn are followed by the game map.
>   The coordinates are calculated starting from the high left corner of
>   the game board.   The user can move by giving a sequence of commands
>   and pressing Enter. The commands are:
>
> - w go up
> - s go down
> - a go left
> - d go right
>
> When the user commands are executed (the user can give many commands
>   at once), a new game situation is drawn. If the lamp charge reac
>   hes 0,
>   the game ends and the text YOU LOSE is printed on the board.
>
> The vampires move randomly in the game, and they take one step for
>   each step the player takes. If the player and a vampire run into each
>   other (even momentarily) the vampire is destroyed. If a vampire tries
>   to step outside the board, or into a place already occupied by another
>   vampire, the move is not executed. When all the vampires are
>   destroyed, the game ends and it prints YOU WIN.   The player starts
>   the game in the position 0,0   Player and vampires can not move out of
>   the dungeon and two vampires cannot step into the same place

**Question**:
How do you refactor this code so that it follows OOP, reads better, is manageable? How can I write method names and classes better? How do you know which entities are to be made separate classes, and how to use classes efficiently?

Feels like there is a lot of bloated classes and repeated code.  Also coding took a long time, spent a lot of time in refactoring and debugging hell. How do you plan and design your code? How do you produce workable, clean code in less time? What do you focus on?

`Movement class` - translates keyboard key into direction

```java
package dungeon;

import useful.BiMap;
import useful.Randomizer;


public class MovementKey {
    private BiMap<Direction, String> movementKeys;
    private Randomizer randomizer;

    enum Direction {
        UP,
        LEFT,
        DOWN,
        RIGHT
    }

    public MovementKey() {
        this.movementKeys = new BiMap<>();
        String[] keys = {"w", "a", "s", "d"};
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            this.movementKeys.put(Direction.values()[i], keys[i]);
        }
        this.randomizer = new Randomizer();
    }

    public static int noOfKeys() {
        return Direction.values().length;
    }

    public Direction getRandomDirection() {
        int randomNumber = randomizer.random(noOfKeys());
        return Direction.values()[randomNumber];
    }

    public String getRandomKey() {
        return movementKeys.get(getRandomDirection());
    }

    public Direction getDirection(String ascii) {
        return movementKeys.getKey(ascii);
    }
}
```

`Character class` - controls the player and the individual vampires

```java
package dungeon;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Character {
    private Point point;
    private Point previousPoint;
    private String symbol;
    private MovementKey movementKey;

    public Character(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.point = new Point();
        this.previousPoint = new Point();
        this.movementKey = new MovementKey();
    }

    public String symbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public Point point() {
        return point;
    }

    public MovementKey movementKey() {
        return movementKey;
    }

    public boolean hasMoved() {
        return !point.equals(previousPoint);
    }

    public boolean isAtThisPosition(Point other) {
        return point.equals(other);
    }

    public void rewindMove() {
        point = previousPoint;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point newPoint) {
        point = newPoint;
    }

    public void move(String command, Dungeon dungeon)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        previousPoint = new Point(point);
        try {
            switch (movementKey.getDirection(command)) {
                case UP:
                    point.setRelativeY(-1);
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    point.setRelativeX(-1);
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    point.setRelativeY(1);
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    point.setRelativeX(1);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid command!");
            }
            if (!dungeon.isInBoundary(point)) {
                rewindMove();
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Command : " + command);
        }
    }
    public String coordinates() {
        return String.format("%s %d %d", symbol, point.x(), point.y());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if (object == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Character other = (Character) object;

        return Objects.equals(symbol, other.symbol)
                && point.equals(other.point);
    }
}
```

`Vampire Group` : controls the actions of the vampires as a group (composition over inheritance)

```java
package dungeon;


import java.util.*;

public class VampireGroup {
    private List<Character> vampires;
    private boolean doesMove;

    public VampireGroup(int count, boolean doesMove) {
        this.vampires = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this.vampires.add(new Character("v"));
        }
        this.doesMove = doesMove;
    }

    public boolean areAshes() {
        return vampires.isEmpty();
    }

    public String symbol() {
        return vampires.get(0).symbol();
    }

    public Set<Point> getPoints() {
        Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();
        for (Character vampire : this.vampires) {
            points.add(vampire.point());
        }
        return points;
    }

    public Character vampireAtPosition(Point point) {
        for (Character vampire : vampires) {
            if (vampire.isAtThisPosition(point)) {
                return vampire;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removeAshes(Point playerPoint) {
        // do nothing if no vampires are found
        vampires.remove(vampireAtPosition(playerPoint));
    }

    public void setInitialCoordinates(int length, int height, 
                                      Set<Point> usedPoints) {
        for (Character vampire : vampires) {
            usedPoints.remove(vampire.point());
            setToRandomCoordinate(length, height, vampire, getPoints());
            usedPoints.add(vampire.point());
        }
    }

    public void setToRandomCoordinate(int length, 
                                      int height, 
                                      Character vampire, 
                                      Set<Point> usedPoints) {
        Point newPoint;
        do {
            newPoint = Point.randomPoint(length, height);
        }
        while (usedPoints.contains(newPoint));
        vampire.setPoint(newPoint);
    }

    public void moveRandomly(Dungeon dungeon, Character vampire, 
                             Set<Point> usedPoints) {
        String key = vampire.movementKey().getRandomKey();
        vampire.move(key, dungeon);
        if (usedPoints.contains(vampire.point())) {
            vampire.rewindMove();
            moveRandomly(dungeon, vampire, usedPoints);
        }
    }

    public void move(Dungeon dungeon) {
        if (!doesMove) {
            return;
        }
        for (Character vampire : vampires) {
            do {
                moveRandomly(dungeon, vampire, dungeon.usedPoints());
            }
            while (!vampire.hasMoved());
        }
    }

    public String coordinates() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character vampire : this.vampires) {
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s\n", vampire.coordinates()));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

`Dungeon class` - draws grid, controls entities in the dungeon (player and vampires)

```java
package dungeon;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Dungeon {
    private int length;
    private int height;
    private int lampCount;
    private Character player;
    private VampireGroup vampires;

    public Dungeon(int length, int height, int lampCount) {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        this.lampCount = lampCount;
        this.player = new Character("@");
        this.vampires = new VampireGroup(2, true);
        this.vampires.setInitialCoordinates(length, height, usedPoints());
    }

    public void printResults() {
        if (vampires.areAshes()) {
            System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
        }
    }

    public boolean isNotClearedWhenPlayerIsAlive() {
        return lampCount > 0 && !vampires.areAshes();
    }


    public Set<Point> usedPoints() {
        Set<Point> usedPoints = new HashSet<>();
        usedPoints.add(player.point());
        usedPoints.addAll(vampires.getPoints());
        return usedPoints;
    }

    public void printStats() {
        System.out.println(lampCount);
        System.out.println();

        printCoordinates();
        System.out.println();

        printGrid(player, vampires, usedPoints());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void playersTurn(String key) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        player.move(key, this);
    }

    public void vampiresTurn() {
        vampires.removeAshes(player.point());
        vampires.move(this);
    }

    public void printCoordinates() {
        System.out.println(player.coordinates());
        System.out.println(vampires.coordinates());
    }

    public boolean isInBoundary(Point point) {
        return  isInRange(point.x(), length)
                && isInRange(point.y(), height);
    }

    public void decrementLampCount() {
        if (player.hasMoved()) {
            lampCount--;
        }
    }

    public boolean isInRange(int value, int min, int max) {
        return value >= min && value < max;
    }

    public boolean isInRange(int value, int max) {
        return isInRange(value, 0, max);
    }

    public void printGrid(Character player, VampireGroup vampires, Set<Point> usedPoints) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                Point currentPoint = new Point(j, i);
                if (usedPoints.contains(currentPoint)) {
                    if (player.isAtThisPosition(currentPoint)) {
                        System.out.print(player);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(vampires.symbol());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print('.');
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

`Point class` - since every character in the dungeon is a point in a 2D grid

```java
package dungeon;

import useful.Randomizer;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Point {
    private static Randomizer randomizer;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        randomizer = new Randomizer();
    }

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public Point(Point other) {
        this(other.x, other.y);
    }

    public static Point randomPoint(int xMin, int xMax, int yMin, int yMax) {
        return new Point(randomizer.random(xMin, xMax),
                randomizer.random(yMin, yMax));
    }

    public static Point randomPoint(int xMax, int yMax) {
        return randomPoint(0, xMax - 1, 0, yMax - 1);
    }

    public int y() {
        return y;
    }

    public int x() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int dx) {
        x = dx;
    }

    public void setY(int dy) {
        y = dy;
    }

    public void setRelativeX(int dx) { setX(x + dx);
    }

    public void setRelativeY(int dy) {
        setY(y + dy);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if (object == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Point other = (Point) object;
        return x == other.x
                && y == other.y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
    }
}
```

`Randomizing class` - Helper class to simplify Random class

```java
package useful;

import java.util.Random;

public class Randomizer extends Random {
    //inclusive
    public int random(int min, int max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    public double randomDouble(double min, int max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextDouble()*(max - min) + min;
    }

    //exclusive
    public int random(int n) {
        return random(0, n - 1);
    }
}
```

`BiMap class` - Helper class used to create |Direction <---> Key| relation.

```java
package useful;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class BiMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private Map<V, K> inversedMap = new HashMap<>();

    public K getKey(V value) {
        return inversedMap.get(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        inversedMap.put(value, key);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        super.putAll(m);
        for (K key : m.keySet()) {
            inversedMap.put(super.get(key), key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        inversedMap.remove(super.get(key));
        return super.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        inversedMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        inversedMap.putIfAbsent(value, key);
        return super.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object key, Object value) {
        inversedMap.remove(value, key);
        return super.remove(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue) {
        inversedMap.remove(oldValue);
        inversedMap.put(newValue, key);
        return super.replace(key, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public V replace(K key, V value) {
        if (super.containsKey(key)) {
            put(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V computeIfAbsent(K key,
                             Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
        V value = super.computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction);
        inversedMap.put(value, key);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V computeIfPresent(K key,
                              BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        V value = super.computeIfPresent(key, remappingFunction);
        inversedMap.put(value, key);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V compute(K key,
                     BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        V value = super.compute(key, remappingFunction);
        inversedMap.put(value, key);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V merge(K key,
                   V value,
                   BiFunction<? super V,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        V replacedValue = super.merge(key, value, remappingFunction);
        inversedMap.remove(value);
        inversedMap.put(replacedValue, key);
        return replacedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceAll(BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> function) {
        inversedMap.clear();
        super.replaceAll(function);
        for (K key : super.keySet()) {
            inversedMap.put(super.get(key), key);
        }
    }
}
```

`UserInterface class` - deals with the commands given by user and executes them

```java
package dungeon;

import java.util.*;

public class UserInterface implements AutoCloseable {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private Dungeon dungeon;

    public UserInterface() {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.dungeon = new Dungeon(5, 5, 14);
    }

    public void executeCommands(String multipleCommands)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (char command : multipleCommands.toCharArray()) {
            dungeon.playersTurn(String.valueOf(command));
        }
        dungeon.vampiresTurn();
        dungeon.decrementLampCount();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (dungeon.isNotClearedWhenPlayerIsAlive()) {
            dungeon.printStats();
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String commandSequence = scanner.next();
                try {
                    executeCommands(commandSequence);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
        dungeon.printResults();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

`Main class`

```java
import dungeon.UserInterface;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (UserInterface ui = new UserInterface()) {
            ui.run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
14

@ 0 0
v 1 2
v 7 8
v 7 5
v 8 0
v 2 9

@.......v.
..........
.v........
..........
..........
.......v..
..........
..........
.......v..
..v.......

ssd
--------------------------
13

@ 1 2
v 8 8
v 7 4
v 8 3
v 1 8

..........
..........
.@........
........v.
.......v..
..........
..........
..........
.v......v.
..........

ssss
--------------------------
12

@ 1 6
v 6 9
v 6 5
v 8 3

..........
..........
..........
........v.
..........
......v...
.@........
..........
..........
......v...

dd
--------------------------
11

@ 3 6
v 5 9
v 6 7
v 8 1

..........
........v.
..........
..........
..........
..........
...@......
......v...
..........
.....v....

ddds
--------------------------
10

@ 6 7
v 6 6
v 5 0

.....v....
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
......v...
......@...
..........
..........

w
--------------------------
9

@ 6 6
v 4 0

....v.....
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
......@...
..........
..........
..........

www
--------------------------
8

@ 6 3
v 4 0

....v.....
..........
..........
......@...
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........

aa
--------------------------
7

@ 4 3
v 4 2

..........
..........
....v.....
....@.....
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........

w
YOU WIN
```

Comment: Please don't edit your code further now answers have been posted. If the community suspects an edit even partially invalidates an existing answer, the edit will be rolled back. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my comments:

### inheritance

composition over inheritance is usually a good principle to follow. However, inheritance has the advantage that the compiler is aware of it and can be used to alert in case of errors. specifically, I saw that in `VampireGroup`, you declared `private List<Character> vampires;`. So theoretically, a player character can be placed in this list. This is where it would be beneficial to have `Player` and `Vampire` classes that inherit from `Character`. with this you could declare `private List<Vampire> vampires;` which is more clear and also makes the compiler guard from accidental addition of `Player` character. the other benefit is that you can further customize player and vampires separately (perhaps they can define their own symbol? more on that later).

### `Direction` enum

this was already mentioned by @glissi. I will add further: in `Character.move()`, you have a `switch` statement with `case` for every movement. the key binding itself is defined in the constructor of `MovementKey`. however, all these pieces of logic and data are tied together. What if you decide to expand your game to allow for diagonal (or other) movements? you will need to make code change in all the above places (possibly more that I didn't see).  in CS, this is called [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). One place that is responsible for all logic and data pertaining to an isolated functionality.

If you wrap your head on how to have the character movement in the enum:  you can have a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) argument to every enum value. The `Function` interface defines a method that takes one argument and returns a value. in your case, it will receive a `Point` of current position and return a new `Point` (can be same instance) in new position. Alternatively, you can have a `Consumer` that returns void (more an that later). the actual body of the functions can be specified as lambda expressions

```
enum Direction {
    UP((point -> {point.setRelativeY(-1); return point;})),
    LEFT((point -> {point.setRelativeX(-1); return point;})),
    ...
    public Function<Point, Point> move;
    Direction(Function<Point, Point> move) {
        this.move = move;
    }
}
```

### Immutability

`Point` class is mutable. it has setter methods that allow callers to alter the state (modify instance variables' values).  In contrast, if you remove the setter methods of `Point`. it becomes immutable. if you want to move a character, you don't alter its point. instead, you assign a new point.  This is similar to the immutable `java.lang.String`. There are several advantages to immutable objects: they can be better tested, are far better suited to be used in multi-threaded system and can be used by Java 8 lambda expressions (that require final objects only).  All these cases are perhaps out of scope or too advanced for this exercise. however, in terms of general good practices, this principle is well known.  That is why I prefer to use `Function` over `Consumer` for movement operation in the enum.

### Separation of Concerns

This [CS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) can be viewed as a higher hierarchy variant of the Single Responsibility principle.  You have a `UserInterface` class that is supposed to be the (only) place that both takes user input and displays data.  Yet, there are several places that affect the output that is displayed on the console: the dungeon prints its own grid, and is responsible for the symbols of the player and of an empty point. `VampireGroup` decides the symbol of a vampire and `MovementKey` hard codes key binding.

now what if you wanted to create an HTML version of your game that is viewed online? what if you wanted to allow users to modify key binding? with Separation of Concerns, you should create a "black box" game engine that has its own api.this api will have a getDungeun() method that will return a string representation of the dungeon. each user interface will know how to read this string representation and display to the user (with possibly different symbols). the string representation can be custom-made, which requires custom-made parser, or use one of the industry standard formats, like XML, JSON where you have ready made parsers.

Comment: How would you used the enum class to get the Direction type from the key pressed (wasd)? Will you need a method like getDirection inside the enum class to get the Direction type from (?) parameter? Will it be good to have an attribute inside the class to hold the values of the possible keys (wasd) ?

Comment: @GraceMathew, like I've written, key binding (mapping of key pressed to direction) belongs to the user interface layer. the game engine should expose the enum values to the user interface layer as the set of acceptable directions (something like `getPossibleDirections()`) and the user interface is responsible for assigning keystrokes (either default or user-assigned). the user interface then accepts user input and does the translation to enum values. these are passed to the game engine as player's turn.

Comment: How do you do the translation to the enum values and apply the function? Suppose the user types "s" (Direction.(?).(???) ?)

Comment: the user interface can keep a `Map<String, Direction>`

Comment: And how would you apply the function? map.get("w").(?);

Comment: the user interface passes list of enum values to the game engine. the game engine is only aware of the enum values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96894/discussion-between-grace-mathew-and-sharon-ben-asher).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think your code is not bad at all. The separation in classes and their respective use is quite okay.

Nevertheless, I have a couple of suggestions that might make your code even better:

#### Try to make things as unsurprising as possible

- Naming one of your classes `Character` is likely to send people on a wrong track, as `Character` is the name of Java's wrapper object class for `char` primitive variables.
- It's a good idea to adhere to naming conventions:
  Methods, which only return a class attribute ("getters") should be named `get<Attribute>`, i.e. `getPoint`, `getPreviousPoint`, `getSymbol`, `getX`, `getY`, etc.
  (you have already done it right for the "setters": `setX`, `setY`, etc)

#### Try to keep things as local and as static as possible

- Can you implement the classes, that are instantiated exactly once during the lifetime of your application in a way, that leverages that?
  Here, the possible candidates `UserInterface`, `Scanner` and `Dungeon` hold the status of your game, so `static` is out of the question. (You could consider using a *Singleton* for these, if you wanted to)
- Methods, that are used only locally should be declared `private`
  e.g. `noOfKeys()` and `getRandomDirection()`, which are both used exclusively from within `MovementKey`.
  (I would even include the functionality of those methods in `getRandomKey()` and erase them altogether).

#### Try to use existing mechanisms

To store the mapping from `Direction` to their respective keys (and vice versa), you create a new bidirectional Map `BiMap`, and use that in `MovementKey`.
In my Opinion, this could be more elegantly implemented by augmenting the enum `Direction` by an attribute which holds the keys, a getter for it and a couple of convenience methods (`getRandomKey()` ...)

This would make `BiMap` and `MovementKey` unnecessary.

Comment: What about using an EnumMap field inside the MovementKey class (which has been made static)?